# no module named 'kronos' in ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu

I'm using AWS (ubuntu instance) and django.

In ubuntu, I did `sudo pip install django-kronos`.

But, When `sudo python3 manage.py runserr --settings=health.settings`

```
Import Error: No module named 'kronos'
```

happens.

Kronos works well in locals. Why I get the error in ubuntu??

Comment: you are installing ```django-kronos``` with ```pip``` but you are execute ```manage.py``` with ```python3``` you have to install ```django-kronos``` to ```python 3``` with ```sudo pip3 install django-kronos```

Comment: It works. Thanks!